# Timeseries: how to filter/take only consistent customers, where it has values (almost) throughout the timeline?

Tags: time-series

Aim: To see which loyal customers (customers that had consistent sales) show high decline in sales overtime.

Condition:
I want to remove one off customers that could bring in false positives. However I do want to maintain the customers who may have zero sales for up to 10% of the timeline (i.e say they can have blanks for 10 out of 100 timeperiods)